# Inline element with line break don't have boundary paddings

Tags: javascript, css

The pictures shows a headline element with `display: inline` defined as well as `padding: 0 15px`:

[image]

As in the picture, the `left padding` on the first line is visible but not the `right padding`. While after the line break, the opposite is true.

My question is if it's possible to have the padding applied on both rows (css trick or javascript) when the inline element spans over several lines?

Comment: can you explain what you have in the picture that was not achievable in CSS?

Comment: @dfsq "as in the picture".... wth?... I'm not getting it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The problem OP's having is that if you have `padding: 0 15px` on the inline element, and this element have content spanning several lines, then the lines with breaks **won't** have proper boundary paddings. That is the problem, and this is illustrated on the picture.

Comment: I was wrong, and today it's actually quite possible.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Note that the OP is based in Europe, and I suspect that his lack of interest may be due to the fact that he may have retired for the night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes correct, you can do it using **boxdecorationbreak:clone**.

Support for `boxdecorationbreak:clone;` it's pretty good and for IE you can use

`white-space:pre-wrap;`

```
h1 {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #B41E81;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight:100;
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 15px;
        -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone; 
        box-decoration-break: clone; 
        white-space:pre-wrap; /*IE*/
    }
```

**Check support**

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak

**From MDN**

**white-space: pre-wrap**

> **pre-wrap** Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at
>    newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

**boxdecorationbreak**: **clone**

> Each box fragment is rendered independently with the specified
>   border, padding and margin wrapping each fragment. The border-radius,
>   border-image and box-shadow, are applied to each fragment
>   independently. The background is drawn independently in each fragment
>   which means that a background image with background-repeat: no-repeat
>   may be repeated multiple times.

**DEMO**

```css
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #B41E81;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight:100;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 15px;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone; 
    box-decoration-break: clone; 
    white-space:pre-wrap; /*IE*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Maximera effekten fore och effekt motet fore och effekt motet</h1>
```

Comment: I set this as correct as it has support for IE defined

Answer (score 4):

This was an old cosmetic issue, but fortunately, these days it actually can be solved easily with the new property `box-decoration-break`. It's already [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-decora) by major vendors except IE (and graceful degradation in this case).

```css
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #B41E81;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h1>Maximera effekten fore och efter motet retul beternium</h1>
```

Comment: `box-decoration-break` is new to me, seems to be a better solution than `display: inline-block`.